# Docker container port issue

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, minecraft, raspbian

I've installed docker on raspbian jessie 8 (IP 192.168.2.2) . I created a docker container with raspbian base image with minecraft installed on in. I opened the port 25565 on the container

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ docker run -d -p 25565:25565 rpi_minecraft

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
b94381cdc3b6        rpi_minecraft       "supervisord -c /etc/"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:25565->25565/tcp   pensive_shockley
```

When I attempt to see if that port is opened I get this error

```
Andrews-iMac:~ Andrew$ telnet 192.168.2.2 25565
Trying 192.168.2.2...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.2.2: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

What is causing this issue? All the relevant ports look open to me?

Comment: Could you give us the image source (repository) you used for rpi_minecraft? Have you tried connecting to the port from the raspbian shell as well? Have you tried running the image on the Andrews-iMac?

Answer (score 0):

Because you opend port 25565 but tested for port 80 with telnet.

`telnet 192.168.2.2 25565`